# Buffered reader causing an infinite loop

Tags: java, while-loop, bufferedreader

I'm currently doing a test project to understand how to read/write into a text file. This is my code:

```
package testings;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Writing_Reading_files {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        File testFile = new File("testFile.dat");
        String test, sName;
        try{
            PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(testFile)));
            test = in.nextLine();
            print.println(test);
            print.close();
        }catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO exception");
            System.exit(0);
        }


        try {
            BufferedReader readerName = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(testFile));
            while(readerName != null) {
                sName = readerName.readLine();
                System.out.println(sName);
            }
            readerName.close();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("FileNotFound");
            System.exit(0);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO exception");
            System.exit(0);
        }


    }

}
```

The while loop results in spitting out the line I put then nulls for an infinite loop if I try While(readerName.readLine != null) it stops the infinite loop but only outputs a null and I don't know where to go from there, I've tried following a youtube tutorial but he has it the same as my code so I'm unsure why I'm null keeps repeating. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

why would `readerName` become `null`? Maybe you mean that the `String` returned by `readLine` is `null`?

Consider

```
BufferedReader readerName = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(testFile));
String sName = readerName.readLine();
while(sName != null) {
    System.out.println(sName);
    sName = readerName.readLine();
}
```

Also consider using `try-with-resources` when opening your file.

Comment: I did the try with resources, same output and also sName and it helped a bit, the output became my input and then only one null

Comment: @NathanGentle Not with this code. It will never print null. 'Output became my input' is meaningless.